# Navigation menu animate toggle

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, jquery-animate, toggle

I have a navigation bar that I'm trying to toggle.
The first animation works, however I can't work out how to slide the menu back off screen.

Here's my code:

```
// SHOW NAVIGATION BAR
$("#menu-btn").click(function() {
    $("nav").animate({
        left: '270px'
    });
    $("#menu-btn").removeClass().addClass("#menu-btn-active");
});

// HIDE NAVIGATION BAR
$("#menu-btn-active").click(function() {
    $("nav").animate({
        left: '-270px'
    });
    $("#menu-btn-active").removeClass().addClass("#menu-btn");
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: They are id's not classes for starters :) Get rid of the hashes on the addClass calls. Do you actually have an element of type `nav`, or is that selector also broken?

Comment: Also your animations both do the same thing (animate left to 270px)!

Comment: I'm selecting all <nav> elements in the HTML.

I've swapped all the ID's for Classes, in the .js, .css and .html files, and has had no effect.

Comment: That was only part of your problems, see answer below.

Comment: The animate left was a pasting error btw. The Hide Navigation section should read left: '-270px'

Comment: Updated to match. Will correct your question now too.

Comment: In future, if you post a JSFiddle link with your question, giving an example of your problem, you will get much better results :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use classes for classes and not IDs. Also, as the event handlers are wired up once, at load time they do not match when you change those classes.

You are also not changing the animation (both animate a `nav` element  to 270px). One of those has to change to somewhere else.

note: You do not need to use `px` and strings for animate. It will translate numbers to pixel values automatically.

Use delegated event handlers, attached to non-changing ancestor elements,  instead:

e.g. something like this (using classes)

```
// SHOW NAVIGATION BAR
$(document).on('click', ".menu-btn", function() {
    $("nav").animate({
        left: '270px'
    });
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("menu-btn-active");
});

// HIDE NAVIGATION BAR
$(document).on('click', ".menu-btn-active", function() {
    $("nav").animate({
        left: '-270px'
    });
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("menu-btn");
});
```

Delegated events handlers *delegate* responsibility to an ancestor element, then apply the jQuery selector at event time (not event registration time). That means they only need to match when the even occurs).

This whole thing can be simplified to a single handler using `toggleClass`, but this will dig you out of the immediate hole for now :)

e.g.

```
// HIDE NAVIGATION BAR
$(document).on('click', ".menu-btn", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active")
    $("nav").animate({
        left: $(this).hasClass('active') ? 270 : -270   // or wherever
    });
});
```

Which, as you are no longer dynamically changing the connecting styles, can simplify back to:

```
// HIDE NAVIGATION BAR
$(".menu-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active")
    $("nav").animate({
        left: $(this).hasClass('active') ? 270 : -270   // or wherever
    });
});
```

Comment: toggleClass is indeed much simpler and much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

How many `$("#menu-btn-active")` are there when you initialize `$("#menu-btn-active").click()`? *None*. The property will be added later, when you click the element. So this does nothing.

In order to get a click that works on present and future elements, use `$(document).on('click, "element", function()...`

Also, use classes, not IDs:

```
$(document).on('click', ".menu-btn", function() {
    $("nav").animate({
        left: '270px'
    });
    $("#menu-btn").removeClass().addClass("menu-btn-active");
});

// HIDE NAVIGATION BAR
$(document).on('click', ".menu-btn-active", function() {
    $("nav").animate({
        left: '270px'
    });
    $("#menu-btn-active").removeClass().addClass("menu-btn");
});
```

Comment: It seems that this solution has the same issue.
The menu opens perfectly, however doesn't close.

Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one. This is 100% working which you are looking.

```
<style type="text/css">
        .toggle{
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background: #f0f;
            left: 0;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>

<div class="toggle"></div>
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.toggle').on('click', function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: '27px'
                });
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('.active').on('click', function () {
                    $(this).animate({
                        left: '0px'
                    });
                    $(this).removeClass('active');

                });
            });
        });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulbaquee/qtus153o/)